# Why after PHP upgrade the program runs from command line but displays PHP code as it is when run in a browser?

Tags: php, apache, debugging, configuration, error-reporting

I'm using **64-bit Ubuntu Linux 14.04** on my machine.

Previously I was using PHP 5.5.32 and everything was working fine.

I just upgraded PHP to latest stable release i.e. 7.0.4 and run the file with URL which I was using to run the file previously.

```
http://localhost/hello.php
```

Following is the content of file **hello.php** :

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   echo 'Hello World!';
?>
```

After hitting the URL in browser the PHP code is getting printed as it is. I don't understand why.
Whereas if I run the program from the command line interface(CLI) i.e. from terminal using following command

```
$ /var/www$ php hello.php
```

I received the expected output as below :

```
Hello World!
```

On terminal.

That indicates the PHP programs are running from terminal but not from the browser. Also it's not telling me what's the issue occurring. It just keep on showing me the whole PHP file as it is.

Someone please help me in running the PHP code from the browser window.

Thanks.

Even I tried below program in the same way, same is the result.

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?
```

Comment: Can you please check the http code of response? Does it have any error in webserver logs?

Comment: did you change port of localhost while updating? check once in php.ini

Comment: shouldn;t this file be in /var/www/html

Comment: @Satya:No, previously when I was using PHP 5.5.32 I was running from /var/www only.

Comment: @Anant:How to check it since I'm  not able to run the file in a browser.

Comment: means to say check by opening `php.ini` file in editor

Comment: @Anant:Where should I get it on my machine?

Comment: why don't first go to @Satya comment ? put your file inside `/var/www/html` and then try to run once.

Comment: @Anant: I created a folder html in /var/www and hit the URL as http://localhost/html/hello.php Same is the result.

Comment: try localhost/hello.php please

Comment: I am not very much familiar with wamp. i think @Satya want to say that there will be a `html` folder automaticlly present so put your code inside that. no need to create folder. 2. If folder is not presented, and you created it, and putted your file, then also call `localhost/hello.php`

Comment: Probably need to rebuild Apache or whatever webserver youre running

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP:How to rebuild Apache? And if such is the case then how the PHP code is working from the command line i.e. terminal?

Comment: Running PHP from the commandline doesnt interact with Apache.  You have to resetup Apache to use the new handlers and extensions.  PHP working on your commandline but not on the web makes it obvious that Apache is the issue.  I can help you later on, but you might want to Google "rebuilding Apache for PHP 7" and see what you find.  If you resolve the problem, make sure to place an answer on here to help others!

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command in order to install Apache module of PHP 7 which is mandatory to execute PHP scripts in Apache.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```